# Does the Django have a ready modules for formatting of distance on a scale?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

For example, the distance is defined by meters.
Procedure should format value on a scale:

```
if distance < 100:
    return '%dm' % distance
elif distance < 1000:
    return '%.0fm' % round(distance, -1)
else:
    import math
    m, km = math.modf(distance / 1000.0)
    if m < 0.01:
        return '%.0fkm' % km
    else:
        return '%.1fkm' % km + round(m, 1)
```

It would be great to use already existing solution.

Update: [django-distanceformatting](https://github.com/mhalairt/django-distanceformatting) is launched, but the question remains open.

Comment: Why don't you want to use your own code? This is such a small functionality scope, that any existing solution will probably contain a lot of other functionality, which you apparently don't need. Importing e.g. a big geocomputing module just to format some numbers in a human-readable way is a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Probably, can be required extension of this code. I do not want to reinvent what already exists.

Comment: Well, without criticizing your code, there is not much of wheel invention going on here... ;-)

Comment: I would like to believe. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some generic unit handling modules for Python, which could be wrapped in a template tag (no specific order):

- [quantities](http://packages.python.org/quantities/)
- [Buckingham](https://code.google.com/p/buckingham/)
- [units](https://bitbucket.org/adonohue/units)
- [Unum](http://home.scarlet.be/be052320/Unum.html)

Maybe one of them gives you what you need. But I still stand to my earlier comment that if you only need so little functionality, you should not need to bother about reinventing the wheel (or your tiny part thereof).

After a closer look at your code, I found some inconsistencies:

- 1.99999 is returned as 1m (should probably be 2m)
- I assume that you want to keep two significant digits, but 1.2 is returned as 1m or 0.12 as 0m
- The last line needs parentheses around the values tuple

Here is a more consistent and concise version of your function (plus a little wrapping around to test):

```
from math import modf
def old_dist_format(distance):
    if distance < 100:
        return '%dm' % distance
    elif distance < 1000:
        return '%.0fm' % round(distance, -1)
    else:
        m, km = modf(distance / 1000.0)
        if m < 0.01:
            return '%.0fkm' % km
        else:
            return '%.1fkm' % (km + round(m, 1))


def dist_format(distance):
    rounded = float('%.2g' % distance)
    km = modf(rounded / 1000.0)
    if km[1]:
        return "%gkm" % (km[0] + km[1])
    else:
        return "%gm" % rounded


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            s = raw_input("> ")
            try:
                d = float(s)
            except ValueError:
                print "Enter number"
                continue
            print "%s\t%s" % (dist_format(d), old_dist_format(d))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print
            break
```

The first line in the new `dist_format()` function always keeps two significant figures. %g leaves out everything from the decimal point if not needed. Caveat: My function will give you exponential notation for (astronomic) distances >= 1000000000.